# Optimization on for loops with ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

From [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#foreach) article,

> hand-written counted loop is about 3x faster

than an enhanced for loop for iterating over arraylists.

Firstly, what do they mean by "hand-written counted loop"? They didn't explicitly elaborate what this means. Secondly, why is it that this holds true only for arraylists and not the other collections?

Comment: hand written is `for(int i=0;i<limit;i++) ...` enhanced is `for(string a:list) ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Firstly, what do they mean by "hand-written counted loop"?

I assume they mean

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    list.get(i);
}
```

> Secondly, why is it that this holds true only for arraylists and not the other collections?

ArrayList supports efficient random access and removing the Iterator can make a small improvement. (or a large relative improvement if you have a loop which doesn't do anything else)

For other collections e.g. LinkedList, it faster to use an Iterator because `get(n)` is slower.  For Set there is no `get(n)`

Comment: thanks peter. so im guessing the efficient random access is because the arraylists internally use arrays, right?

Comment: thanks matt. one last question. what holds true for arraylists in this case must therefore hold true for vectors too, correct? since they both use arrays internally.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, though do keep in mind that `Vector` is synchronized while `ArrayList` is not. I don't really see much use in `Vector` these days...

Comment: Vector is IMHO a legacy class which was replaced in Java 1.2 by ArrayList in 1998. The problem with Vector is that the only reasons to use it are a) you have a library which insists you use it b) you need thread safety.  Unfortunately Vector doesn't give thread safety for using Iterator or repeated calls to `get(n)` so there is no good reason to use a Vector in a loop like this.

Answer (score 5):

All the answers to this question (at the time of me writing this there are three answers), are wrong.

For Android you should NOT do this for hand written loops!

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    list.get(i);
}
```

ABOVE IS WRONG!

The loop must look like this (size is temporarily copied into its own variable):

```
int size = list.size();
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    list.get(i);
}
```

Otherwise there will be a lookup penalty for each iteration of the loop! If you read the article linked from the question carefully, you will see that google recommends this pattern as well.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised Android is this poorly optimized.

Comment: that's certainly not true. Many languages, and runtimes like the JVM, will inline such calls. Sometimes there are even special optimizations with loop detection. Since the internal size field is not volatile, it can safely assume no concurrent access, thus achieving the exact same performance as example one, i.e. stack vs heap.

Comment: From the horses mouth: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops

Answer (score 0):

A hand-written counted loop looks like the loops in `zero()` or `one()` in that same article:

```
List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
// populate the list...

for (int i=0; i<foos.size(); i++) {
    Foo foo = foos.get(i);
    // do something with foo
}
```

Comment: in other words, avoid using enhanced for loops with arraylists but use it with everything else?

Comment: Not necessarily. Unless the list is large - `ArrayList` or not - the performance difference likely won't matter.

Comment: @OckhamsRazor If you read the article, it recommends always using the enhanced for loop unless you're dealing with an ArrayList **and** performance is critical (most of the time it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

This is a hand-written counted loop. What they mean is that you manually wrote a loop that counts out each element in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length; ++i) {
```

This holds true for arraylists given their underlying implementation. Because the enhanced for loop has to work generically, it cannot assume certain things; such as a index start and end point.